# Datatable error 404 con Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, datatables, codeigniter-3, virtualhost

Tengo un sistema hecho con codeigniter

El sistema esta montado en Servidor SuSE y estoy utilizando VirtualHost

El problema, es que cuando hago peticiones a un controlador para cargar una tabla a traves de datatable con server side procesing, el sistema me arroja un error 404.

**Esta es la configuracion del Virtual Host**

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin miCorreo@miEmpres.com
    ServerName directorio
    ServerAlias directorio
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/directorio

    # if not specified, the global error log is used
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/directorioTelefonico-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/directorioTelefonico-access_log combined

<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/directorio">

        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride None

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
            Require all granted
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Configuracion del base_url en el archivo config.php**

$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

**Configuracion de mi Escrip js**

```js
//Server side processing

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tblcontactos').DataTable({
          //'paging'      : true,
          //'lengthChange': false,
          //'searching'   : true,
          //'ordering'    : true,
          //'info'        : true,
          "lengthMenu": [[15, 50, 100, 500], [15, 50, 100, 500]],
          "autoWidth"   : false,
          "stateSave"   : true, // mantiene la busqueda cuando se recarga la pagina
          "processing"  : true,
          "serverSide"  : true,
          "ajax":{
                        "url": rutaContactosSP,
                        "type": "POST",
                      "data":{ get_csrf_token_name : get_csrf_hash }
         },
          "columns": [
                      //{ "data": "id" },
                      { "data": "nombre" },
                      { "data": "empresa" },
                     { "data": "departamento" },
                      { "data": "extension" },
                      { "data": "email" }
          ],
    }) // fin de $('#tblcontactos').DataTable({
}) // fin de document.ready.function
```

**Configuracion de mi Vista**

```js
    // impresion de variable para uso en Scrip contactos
    var rutaContactosSP     ="<?php echo base_url('ControllerContactos/posts');?>";
    var base_url            ="<?php echo base_url();?>";
    var get_csrf_token_name ="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>";
    var get_csrf_hash       ="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>";
```

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="box">
               <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="tblcontactos" class="table table-bordered"  style="font-size:11px;font-family:Comic Sans MS,arial,verdana">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th style="width: 20%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Contacto</th>
                                  <th style="width: 20%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Empresa</th>
                                  <th style="width: 20%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Departamento</th>
                                  <th style="width: 2%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Extension</th>
                                  <th style="width: 5%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Email</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                   </table>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLADOR CONTACTOS**

ControllerContactos.php

```html
<?php
//  Controlador de la vista principal es decir del Index
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ControllerContactos extends CI_Controller{

  function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('ModelContacto');
  }

 // Carga la vista principal de las Empresa que en este caso es un listado de Empresas
  public function index(){
   $datos['titulo'] = 'Directorio Telefonico';
       $datos['header'] = 'template/header';
   $datos['menu']   = 'template/menu';
   $datos['formulario']  = 'contactos/index'; // Listado de Empresas
   $datos['footer']  = 'template/footer';
   $datos['menu2']  = 'template/menu2';
   $datos['piedepagina']  = 'template/pieDePagina';
   $datos['modulo']   = 'Contactos';
   $datos['accion'] = 'Listado de Contactos';
   $this->load->view('template/template',$datos);
  }

  // procesando server side processing
  public function posts(){
  $columns = array(
    0 =>'nombre',
    1 =>'empresa',
    2=> 'departamento',
    3=> 'extension',
    4=> 'email',
   );
 
   $limit  = $this->input->post('length');
  $start  = $this->input->post('start');
  $order   = $columns[$this->input->post('order')[0]['column']];
  $dir     = $this->input->post('order')[0]['dir'];
  $totalData  = $this->ModelContacto->allposts_count();
                $totalFiltered  = $totalData;

   if(empty($this->input->post('search')['value'])) {
    $posts = $this->ModelContacto->allposts($limit,$start,$order,$dir);
   }else {
    $search = $this->input->post('search')['value'];
   $posts =  $this->ModelContacto->posts_search($limit,$start,$search,$order,$dir);
   $totalFiltered = $this->ModelContacto->posts_search_count($search);
   }

   $data = array();
   if(!empty($posts)){
    foreach ($posts as $post){
     $nestedData['id']        =  $post->id;
     $nestedData['nombre']     =  $post->nombre;
     $nestedData['empresa']     =  $post->empresa;
     $nestedData['departamento'] =  $post->departamento;
     $nestedData['cargo']     =  $post->cargo;
     $nestedData['extension']   =   $post->extension;
       $nestedData['email']     =  $post->email;
     $nestedData['estado']    =  $post->estado;
     $nestedData['idemp']     =  $post->idemp;
     
     $data[] = $nestedData;

    }
   }

   $json_data = array(
      "draw"            => intval($this->input->post('draw')),
      "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),
      "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
      "data"            => $data
         );

   echo json_encode($json_data);
 }
}
?>
```

**MODEL CONTACTO**

ModelContacto.php

```html
<?php

class ModelContacto extends CI_Model{



    // ##################### metodos server side processing ####################

    // se omiten los usuarios que no estan activos
    public function getAll(){ //getEmpresas
        $this->db->select('c.id,c.nombre as cnombre, e.nombre as enombre,e.dim, c.departamento, c.cargo, c.extension, c.celular, c.email,c.estado,e.id as idemp');
        $this->db->from('contactos c, empresas e');
        $this->db->where('c.estado = 1');
        $this->db->where('c.empresa = e.id');

        $r = $this->db->get();

        return $r->result();
    }



    function allposts_count(){
        $query = $this->db
                          ->where("estado = 1")
                          ->get("contactos");

        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    function allposts_count(){
        $query = $this->db
                          ->where("estatus = 1")
                          ->get("contactos");

        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    function allposts($limit,$start,$col,$dir){
          $where1 = "(c.estado =1 and c.estatus = 1)";

          $this->db->select('c.id,c.nombre as nombre, empresas.nombre as empresa, c.departamento, c.cargo, c.extension, c.email,c.estado,c.empresa as idemp');
          $this->db->from('contactos c');
          $this->db->join('empresas', 'c.empresa = empresas.id', 'Inner');
          $this->db->where($where1);
          $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
          $this->db->order_by($col,$dir);

          $r = $this->db->get();

          if($r->num_rows()>0){
              return $r->result();
          }else{
              return null;
          }
    }


    function posts_search($limit,$start,$search,$col,$dir){
        $where1 = "(c.estado =1 and c.estatus = 1)";
        $where2 = "(  c.nombre    like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.cargo    like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.extension        like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.email    like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or empresas.nombre   like '%".$search."%')";

        $this->db->select('c.id,c.nombre as nombre, empresas.nombre as empresa, c.departamento, c.cargo, c.extension, c.email,c.estado,c.empresa as idemp');
        $this->db->from('contactos c');
        $this->db->join('empresas', 'c.empresa = empresas.id', 'Inner');
        $this->db->where($where1);
        $this->db->where($where2);
        $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
        $this->db->order_by($col,$dir);

        $r = $this->db->get();

        if($r->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $r->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    function posts_search_count($search){
        $where1 = "(c.estado =1 and c.estatus = 1)";
        $where2 = "(  c.nombre     like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.cargo     like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.extension         like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or c.email     like '%".$search."%'";
        $where2.= "or empresas.nombre    like '%".$search."%')";

        $this->db->select('c.id,c.nombre as nombre, empresas.nombre as empresa, c.departamento, c.cargo, c.extension, c.email,c.estado,empresas.id as idemp');
        $this->db->from('contactos c');
        $this->db->join('empresas', 'c.empresa = empresas.id', 'Inner');
        $this->db->where($where1);
        $this->db->where($where2);

        $r = $this->db->get();

        if($r->num_rows()>0){
              return $r->num_rows();
        }else{
              return 0;
        }
    }
    // fin de metodos server side processing
}

 ?>
```

**NOTA ESTOY USANDO CODEIGNITER Y LA PLANTILLA ADMIN DE BOOSTRAB, LOS METODOS DEL MODELO **

Ahora mostrado todo esto les comento que el  sistema funciona a la perfeccion en un mi host local, es decir cuando desarrolle el sistema en mi pc.

y esta es la configuracion del base_url en mi equipo local
$config['base_url'] = 'http://172.16.16.179:8080/directorio/

**Esta es la configuracion de mi archivo .htaccess**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) directorio/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ directorio/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**IMAGENES DEL ERROR**

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 3]

Espero haber sido lo mas espeficico posible agradeceria cualquier ayuda, todo apunta a que tengo mal la configuracion del base_url, pero no estoy 100% seguro..

For English speakers, I would also appreciate your help. I do not have problems speaking in English.

Comment: Bienvenido de preferencias que tu codigo no sean imagenes si no texto, es mas facil para probrarlo

Comment: Gracias Raul por tu recomendacion, ya añadi el codigo

Answer (score 0):

para los que se les presente este problema, les comento que se debia a la configuracion del .htacces y la configuracion del virtualhost

**Archivo .htaccess**

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
       
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
       
</IfModule>
```

**Virtual Host**

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin correo@empresa.com
    ServerName directorio
    ServerAlias directorio
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/directorio

    # if not specified, the global error log is used
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/directorio-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/directorio-access_log combined

    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/directorio">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
         #Allow from all ->> he aqui un problema
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```